# $p$-adic Galois representation and Étale homology

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, etale-cohomology, galois-representations, p-adic-hodge-theory

Let $X$ be a smooth proper scheme over some $p$-adic field $K$. The "usual" way to get a Galois representation out of this is to consider the étale cohomology (either $p$ or $\ell$-adic). Then $p$-adic Hodge theory tells me that these are "nice" by which I mean Hodge-Tate.

Another way that I'd think of would be to consider the étale homology $H_{n}(X_{\overline{K}},\mathbb{Q}_p)$. Do we know anything about these representations, for instance, are they Hodge-Tate? Are they "interesting" (i.e. non-trivial?).

Comment: Aren't these just the duals to étale cohomology?

Comment: As I understand it, yes. But are "niceness" properties preserved under taking duals?

Comment: The only one I can think of that isn't is that Frobenius eigenvalues are algebraic integers (On the duals, they're inverses of algebraic integers).